# Questions on a cone defined by elementary symmetric functions

Tags: real-analysis, inequalities, elliptic-pde

Let $1\le k\le n$ be given integers. Define the following cone
$$\Gamma_k=\{\lambda\in\mathbb{R}^n| S_j(\lambda)>0, j=1, ..., k\},$$
where $S_j(\lambda)$ is the $j$th elementary symmetric function of $\lambda$.

I have some questions about the cone, which are probably known. Any pointers to literature or sharing some ideas of proof is appreciated.

Question 1. How to show that $\Gamma_k$ is convex in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Question 2. How to show that if $\lambda=(\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n)\in \Gamma_k$, then $\frac{\partial S_k(\lambda)}{\partial \lambda_j}>0$ for any $j=1, \ldots, n$.

Question 3. In [this paper by Lin and Trudinger](https://sci-hub.se/https://doi.org/10.1017/S0004972700013770) it is stated that Eq.(7), Eq.(8) are respectively Newton and Maclaurin inequalities, quoted from Ref. [6], but I didn't find them there. Are there any other references where I can find proofs of these inequalities?

Comment: For question 1, with $n=k=2$ we have $S_2(x,y) = x y$ which is positive in the first and third quadrant and negative in the second and fourth. This is not convex, and the point $(x,y)=(-1,-1)$ also creates difficulties for question 2: $\frac{\partial(xy)}{\partial x} = y < 0$. But perhaps $\Gamma_k$ consists of $2^{k-1}$ connected components, each of which might be convex?

Comment: @SamZackrisson For $(x,y)\in\Gamma_2$ one also needs $S_1(x,y)=x+y>0$.

Comment: @Victor Ah, I completely missed that it is required for all j up to k. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, $\Gamma_k$ is determined by k inequalities.

Comment: I can see that (2) implies (1). Indeed, (2) applied iteratively implies that the projection of $\Gamma_k$ on any coordinate subspace $\lambda_I$, $I\subset \{1,\ldots,k\}$, lies inside $\Gamma_{k-|I|}$. On the other hand, for $\lambda,\mu\in\Gamma_k$,
$$
S_k(\lambda+\mu) = \sum_{I\sqcup J=\{1\ldots k\}} S_{|I|}(\lambda_I)S_{|J|}
(\mu_J)
$$
and is therefore positive being a sum of products of positive numbers. This proves (2) => (1). Maybe (3) implies (2)?

Comment: Indeed, (2) follows from equation (7) from the paper.  (7) implies $S_{k-1}^2\geq S_k S_{k-2}$. Assuming $\lambda\in\Gamma_k$ let us prove that $S_{k-1}(\lambda_1\ldots\lambda_{k-1})>0$. The case $\lambda:=\lambda_k\leq 0$ is straightforward. Assume it is $<0$. By induction we can assume $S_1\ldots S_{k-2}$ on $\lambda':=(\lambda_1\ldots\lambda_{k-1})$ are all positive. The conditions $S_{k-1}(\lambda)>0$ and $S_k(\lambda)>0$ can be written as $\begin{cases}S_{k-2}(\lambda')\lambda+S_{k-1}(\lambda')>0\\ S_{k-1}(\lambda')\lambda+S_{k}(\lambda')>0.\end{cases}$

Comment: By contradiction assuming $S_{k-1}(\lambda')\leq 0$ but remembering that $S_{k-2}(\lambda')>0$, we multiply the second inequality by $S_{k-2}$: $$S_kS_{k-2}>-S_{k-2}S_{k-1}\lambda\geq S_{k-1}^2.$$

Comment: Sorry for a typo, above "Assume it is $<0$" should be read "Assume it is $>0$".

Comment: Oops, I realized my argument (2) => (1) has a mistake.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I agree that (2) follows from equation (7) from the paper.